# How do I add the value beside the matched object?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

> I want to find how do I add all the value beside the matching names?

The excel picture that I am trying to solve[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFthi.jpg)

At first, I tried to use Vlookup to find the value. However, it only gives 1 value. After that I tried using Countif(). However, countif() only gives me the number of times the name appear on the list. Is there a excel function to add up all these without manually add in 1 by 1 using if match then add for every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMIF for this.

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$8,E2,$B$2:$B$8)
```

[image]

Generally speaking, if you don't know what function to use, I recommend browsing the available functions for something that looks like it might do what you want. You can either use the Function Library on the Formulas tab, or click 'Insert Function':

[image]

You can see that by typing "add" into the "Search for a function box", I have a list of functions to try. SUMIF is in the list:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck here for the longest time.